# Clearing the lowest set bit of a number

Tags: c++, c, bitwise-operators, bit

I can see in this tutorial on bit manipulation, under the heading "Extracting every last bit", that -

> Suppose we wish to find the lowest set bit of x (which is known to be
>   non-zero). If we subtract 1 from x then this bit is cleared, but all
>   the other one bits in x remain set.

I don't understand how this statement is true.

If we take `x = 110`, subtracting 1 would give `101`.

Here, the lowest set bit is not cleared. Can anyone tell me how I'm approaching this problem in a wrong way?

Comment: The lowest set bit in `110` is the middle one. In `101`, the middle bit is cleared.

Comment: The accepted answer is correct: think about it. How does 2s complement work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After subtracting 1, you need to & the two values.  e.g.

`int bitremoved = x & (x-1);`

In your example you end up with binary 100.

Comment: But binary 100 does not meet the second part of the description: "but all the other one bits in x remain set."

Comment: @SailsMan63 its quite possible that the tutorial quoted was... less than complete/ideal (or not fully quoted).  The solution of `x & (x-1)` *is* the correct approach to clearing the lowest bit.

Comment: Read this [Intel Haswell new instructions](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2011/06/13/haswell-new-instruction-descriptions-now-available), under BLSR. If this is not correct I will vote to close.

Comment: Turns out that it wasn't fully quoted, and for that matter wasn't the proper instructions for the operation.  The full tutorial is from TopCoder [Algorithim Tutorials - A bit of fun: fun with bits](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=bitManipulation) (the tutorial is correct, the interpretation of it in this question is incorrect).